# Sort Table by the order of the Array not Alphabetical

Tags: angularjs, arrays, sorting, constants, angularjs-orderby

like in the Title mentioned I want to Sort my Table by the Order of my Array and not the Normal way -> Alphabetical.

```
   This is the Array with the Constants.
    .constant("appConfig", {
        "status": [
            "In Work",
            "Review",
            "Again in Edit",
            "Finished"
        ]
    })
//in the html then the standard code for sorting atm Alphabetical
       <th>
        <a href="#" ng-click="sortType='Status.status';sortReverse = !sortReverse">
          Status
          <span ng-show="sortType == 'Status.status' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
          <span ng-show="sortType == 'Status.status' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
        </a>
        <select class="form-control" ng-model="select.Status.status">
          <option value="">-- Select --</option>
          <option ng-repeat='status in $ctrl.aStatus' >{{status}}</option>
        </select>
      </th>
      <tr dir-paginate="t in $ctrl.getTasks() | filter:{name:k}| orderBy: sortType:sortReverse| filter:select|itemsPerPage: 10 as results">

    <td class="td-selects">
                  <span uib-tooltip="{{t.notice}}" tooltip-popup-delay='500'>
                  {{t.Status.status}}</span>
                </td>
```

So it is sorting
Again in Edit
Finished
In Work
Review
And same in Reverse. But it shall be in the "Todo Chain"->like in the Constant Array be. So like this
In work
Review
Again in Edit
Finished
And Reverse.
Can I somehow add $index or something to the sort that it works like that?

Answer (score 0):

Can you create a `plunker/fiddle` and post the link for the same for better understanding?

Comment: you should be put it as a comment

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fjkcg
That is not mine code but as Example. If you sort the First name Colum its sorted Alphabetical. My wish is that if I click on sort it should be sorted like in the Array. For the example it would be John->Frank->Sue //see at $scope.data in .js